# Merge Two Lists LeetCode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've solved the problem on Repl.it website, but when I submitted the code on LeetCode it gave a typeError, that I'm going to paste it here:

```
Line 29 in solution.js
         throw new TypeError(__serialize__(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type 
ListNode");
         ^
TypeError: [] is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode
Line 29: Char 20 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
Line 13: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
Line 1200: Char 30 in loader.js (Module._compile)
Line 1220: Char 10 in loader.js (Object.Module._extensions..js)
Line 1049: Char 32 in loader.js (Module.load)
Line 937: Char 14 in loader.js (Function.Module._load)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
Line 17: Char 47 in run_main_module.js
```

And here's the code:

```
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
  let i = 0, j = 0;
  var out = [];
  while(i < l1.length || j < l2.length) {
    if(j == l2.length || i < l1.length && l1[i] < l2[j]) {
      out.push(l1[i++]);
    } else {
      out.push(l2[j++]);
    }
  }
  return out;
};
```

I really don't know where the problem is... if someone could help I would be grateful

Comment: It is expecting ListNode as a return from the method and you are returing an array.

Comment: Oh... I see, so any ideas on how I could do that?... I did some search but I didn't quite get them...

Comment: Check this https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/443961/javascript-solution-based-on-merging-two-sorted-lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) merge question, not a regular array merging. This'd pass through:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    var dummy = {
      val : -1,
      next : null
    };
    var curr = dummy;
    while (l1 && l2) {
        if (l1.val > l2.val) {
            curr.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        } else {
            curr.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    
    curr.next = l1 || l2;

    return dummy.next;
};
```

This is how your list would look like:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We'd write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

You have done,

```
L1[1,2] + L2[3,4] = L1L2[1,2,3,4]
```

If we have L1

```
    L1{
        val:1,
        next:{
            val:2,
            next: null
        }
    }
```

And we have L2

```
    L2{
        val:3,
        next:{
            val:4,
            next: null
        }
    }
```

And we want to develop L1 + L2

```
    L1L2{
        val:1,
        next:{
            val:2,
            next: {
                val:3,
                next: {
                    val:4,
                    next:null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then using JS We can do it in a following manner,

```
function ListNode(val, next) {
    this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val);
    this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next);
}

function mergeTwoLists(l1, l2) {
    let temp = new ListNode(0);
    let current = temp;

    while (l1 !== null && l2 !== null) {
        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            current.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        } else {
            current.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

    // If one of the lists is longer than the other
    if (l1 !== null) {
        current.next = l1;
    } else {
        current.next = l2;
    }

    return temp.next;
}

// Example usage
const L1 = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2, null));
const L2 = new ListNode(3, new ListNode(4, null));

const result = mergeTwoLists(L1, L2);
```